Youtube API Python, Is search not deterministic?
I want to use the Youtube API to collect some video data to train on data analysis. For this, I use the search method of the Youtube API. However, at each search, I don't get the same results. For example, with this code :
request1 = youtube.search().list(part="snippet", type='video', q="risotto", maxResults=40, order='date')
info1 = request1.execute()
request2 = youtube.search().list(part="snippet", type='video', q="risotto", maxResults=40, order='date')
info2 = request2.execute()

I get 2 similar results, but some videos (in snippet.items) are different, which is weird to me since I ordered the result by date and searched a precise keyword (for which there shouldn't be a lot of new videos every execution). Is this normal ? Is there a way to avoid this ?
I tried ordering by date, views and relevance, but it still gave me different results. From an execution to another, I sometimes get the same result, or the same result as a previous execution. So it just seems random, but this isn't supposed to happen.

I agree that it's not logical, but why is it an issue? Is exhaustivity or reproducibility an issue for you?

check the issue forum search has never been consistant
